# ruby/rails variable scope before assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-model-serializers

UPDATE:

Thanks guys, went with this:

```
def add_minor
  if @user.minors.count <= 2
    render :json =>  @user.profile.minors << Minor.find(params[:minor_id]), :status => 200
  else
    render :json => '', :status => 409
  end
end
```

is there a better way to handle the assignment of this res property here to keep it available to render call? Overall I am just wondering how to improve this pretty smelly method.

```
respond_to :json
def add_minor
  res = ''
  unless @user.minors.count > 2
    minor = Minor.find(params[:minor_id])
    res =  @user.profile.minors << minor
    status = 200
  else
    status = 409
  end
  render :json => res, :status => status
end
```

Comment: This is going to be a matter of opinion, but I wouldn't use variables in this simple case for `res` and `status`. And I would reverse the logic and use `if` (`unless-else` makes my brain hurt). So have `if  @user.minors.count <= 2` followed by `render :json => @user.profile.minors << minor, :status => 200` and the `else` be just `render :json => '', :status => 409`. I think the whole thing will be cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def add_minor
  if @user.minors.count > 2
    render :json => '', :status => 409
  else
    @user.profile.minors << Minor.find(params[:minor_id])
    render :json => @user.profile.minors, :status => 200
  end
end
```